"reset" Ubuntu 24.04 because of broken packages?
Last night, I did an apt dist-upgrade to update from 22.04 to 24.04 - but obviously there was something wrong, because I got a number of Python related errors from apt after installing.  I noticed because it wouldn't let me install vim.  At first, the errors were like:
 libpython3.12t64 : Depends: libpython3.12-stdlib (= 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) but 3.12.7-1+jammy1 is to be installed

...but after looking around and trying various things, I seem to have made it much worse; as far as I can tell, anything Python related is messed up.  I am certain that it's related to various bits in /etc/apt/sources.list.d.  Currently, when I try to apt --fix-broken install, I get this error:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 network-manager : Depends: netplan.io (>= 0.106~) but it is not installed
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.12.3-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
           Depends: python3.12 (>= 3.12.3-0~) but it is not installable
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: python3.12 but it is not installable
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk : Depends: update-manager but it is not installed
 ubuntu-session : Depends: gnome-shell (>= 3.37.91) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

Unfortunately, looking for answers here and elsewhere gives a jumble  of stuff sometimes over a decade old (!).
What I'd like right now is a suggestion for how to declare "bankruptcy" and force reinstallation of the basics; I can recover any additional software later, but it's hard to get a description of what SHOULD be in /etc/apt/sources.list.d to make this happen that isn't dangerously out of date.
Suggestions?  I'm hesitant to try more for fear of making it even worse (which I've already done)
EDIT: - Since there seems to be some confusion what "fix" I'm asking for, I think what I need is to remove all non-stock bits from /etc/apt/sources.list.d and somehow use apt to reinstall those packages that come with the system so I can recover.  Right now, basically nothing is working.  I'm happy to try other stuff, but it would be great if they were tips from this decade.

The command apt install dist-upgrade which you provide in your question wouldn't have harmed your system in any way, instead it would have given the error message unable to locate package dist-upgrade. So you must have done something different, it remains unclear.

ugh, yes, apt dist-upgrade without the "install".  I'll fix.

There is no "reset" feature. Reset = Reinstall. Be sure to back up your data first, lest your problems multiply.

Also remind: apt dist-upgrade does not upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04, this command does not perform a release upgrade. Read the man man pages man apt, man apt-get.

"I think what I need is to remove all non-stock bits from /etc/apt/sources.list.d" Yes, that's a big part of it. Review those sources, recall what packages you installed from those sources, and then uninstall those packages. If you have aptitude or synaptic installed already, they have some extra tools for identifying the self-inflicted conflicts, but if not then a good memory will work just as well.

There is no "reset" option. You'll have to just reinstall your system.  There is no "revert" command when you break packages on your system.
You will need to backup the data you want to keep to external media and then reinstall.

sudo apt remove --purge libpython3.12-stdlib libpython3.12-minimal
sudo apt install python3.12 python3.12-venv
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vim
this helped... Ubuntu 24.04
